# One-way binding doesn't work after manual update

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using Angular 1.5.8, I would like to have an HTML text field that always displays the value of some model value, but I need to use one-way update only (model-to-view update, but not view-to-model). It works but if this text field is manually modified (user types something, which is allowed), the text field doesn't get updated anymore, even after a few model updates. Using Chrome's Developer tools, I can clearly see the `value` attribute of my `<INPUT>` being updated, even once the model is updated after a manual update, but the HTML view doesn't reflect this. Any idea why?

This text field is used to display the current page number: the user can freely edit its content without any page change, but when [s]he hits the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the entered page number is sent to the model/controller.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pageCtrlPanel" ng-controller="PageController as pageCtrl">
    Page <input id="pageNumTxt" type="text" value="{{pageData.currPage}}">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
app.controller("PageController", function($scope) {
    $scope.pageData = .....;
});

app.directive('keyListener', function(dialogService) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            var pageController = angular.element( $('#pageCtrlPanel') ).scope().pageCtrl;
            var target = $( event.target );
            scope.$apply(function() {
                // .......
                if ( target.is( 'input' ) ) {
                    if ( target.is( '#pageNumTxt' ) && event.which == 13 ) {
                        // ENTER key pressed on page selection text field
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var newPage = parseInt( $('#pageNumTxt').val() , 10);
                        if (!pageController.goToPage(newPage)) {
                            alert('Invalid page number (should be in [1 ~ ' + pageController.getLastPage() + ']).');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            scope.$digest();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Asaign `ng-model="pageData.currPage"` in the input field.

Comment: value attribute is different than value property. User input does not affect the attribute which is only used by browser to set property when page is loaded

Comment: create a demo...this is hard to follow and not really clear what you are trying to do (or why)

Comment: @Developer If I'm right, `ng-model` will imply a two-way binding, which I don't want

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry if I mixed up attribute/property (not sure to understand your comment though). I will try to create a demo for this, thanks for the advice

Comment: don't apologize...am trying to point out an important distinction

Comment: That's right. Im confused - initially you state to have _model-to-view update, but not view-to-model_ and toward the end you want the changes made in textbox to be reflected in the model!

Comment: @Developer Yes, but the view-to-model update is not automatic, I do it manually in the above code only once the ENTER key is hit (in order to avoid several updates, like for example "42" -> "4" -> "" -> "1" -> "13" to go to page 13, while being on page 42)

Comment: If that's the exact requirement,  then you can avoid doing all these workarounds - set `ng-model` and `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}"` so that the model update happens only when you tab out or similar way

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/toresenneseth.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/update-the-model-on-enter-key-pressed-with-angularjs/amp/

Comment: This seems like a terrible use of angular

Comment: @Developer Thanks, it works with `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'submit'}"`  (triggered only when ENTER is hit, not on focus lost). If you make it an answer, I will upvote/accept it ;)

Comment: @devqon Thanks for the constructive comment... I know it's bad Angular use, that's why I'm asking questions to learn how to build better Angular Apps. Btw the comment written by "Developer" really helped me in this goal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's requirement (after discussing about the requirements in the comments), the model update should happen only when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

For achieving this, set `ng-model` and `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}"` so that the model update happens only when you tab out or similar way. For updating the model on submit (i.e. when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed), use `ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'submit'}"`